# What can cause UnhandledAlertException errors?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am new to selenium and I was working with having to run my test at different browser and versions. After having to run it in Firefox 15, I uninstalled Firefox15 and installed Firefox17, which is when the error stared.

The firefoxdriver was called, but it gives this error:

```
Failure: OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException : Modal dialog present
Build info: version: '2.26.0', revision: '18041', time: '2012-11-01 19:33:38'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_09'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
Session ID: e1417203-a392-4f74-948e-2108fb2bbe34
```

It actually opens the page, but then it refreshes it and then some alerts come out.

I have tried uninstalling it and installing Firefox 15 again but nothing works. Internet Explorer works fine so I know it was not Selenium, but the Firefox driver.

I am using Selenium 2.26.0 and running it by seleniumRC.

Comment: well, it seems to me that when ffox starts running some modal windows appear like "would you like to me ffox your default browser" or something like that and that's why selenium fails to start

Comment: I have debugged it and it seems that after the page was reloaded it sets my driver to null that is why it caused some error....Is there a driver for firefox like in IE it has one....or a way to clean up firefox?....

Comment: static WebDriver driver;
    BeforeClass
    public static void firefoxSetUp() throws MalformedURLException {

          DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
} 
  Before
    public void homePageRefresh() throws IOException {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.get("login.base.url");
    }
try this initialization of webDriver.

Comment: thnx for the responses @eugene.polschikov..yep that really did the trick...but I have founded out that the site I was testing was actually broken...and it actually throws those alerts that I have found...but one thing I have learned is that selenium 2.26 detects alerts that are present that is not expected and stops executing more commands.....unlike 2.25 which executes the command first until error arrives....2.26 saves more time especially if you are using Webdriverwait like me....

But really thanks to your replies it really saved me the time on detecting it....but sorry for my mistake....

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code to supress the alerts :

```
DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR,UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
driver =new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```